# SQL Server R Services - outputting data to database table, performance

Tags: sql-server, r, microsoft-r

I noticed that rx* functions (eg. `rxKmeans`, `rxDataStep`) insert data to SQL Server table in a row-by-row fashion when outFile parameter is set to a table. This is obviously very slow and something like bulk-insert would be desirable instead. Can this be obtained and how to do it?

Currently I am trying to insert about 14 mln rows to a table by invoking `rxKmeans` function with `outFile` parameter specified and it takes about 20 minutes.

Example of my code:

```
clustersLogInitialPD <-  rxKmeans(formula = ~LogInitialPD
                     ,data = inDataSource
                     ,algorithm = "Lloyd" 
                     ,centers = start_c
                     ,maxIterations = 1
                     ,outFile = sqlLogPDClustersDS
                     ,outColName = "ClusterNo"
                     ,overwrite = TRUE
                     ,writeModelVars = TRUE
                     ,extraVarsToWrite = c("LoadsetId", "ExposureId")
                     ,reportProgress = 0
)
```

`sqlLogPDClustersDS` points to a table in my database.

I am working on SQL Server 2016 SP1 with R Services installed and configured (both in-database and standalone). Generally everything works fine except this terrible performance of writing rows to database tables from R scrip.

Any comments will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is your input dataset a SQL table, or a data frame/xdf file? If the former, have you tried changing to the inSqlServer compute context?

Comment: inDataSource is a SQL Query and I set the compute context to SQL Server:

Comment: Has anyone resolved this? Particularly if inDataSource is NOT a SQL query or table but, rather, a data.frame from R code?

Answer (score 2):

I brought this up on [this Microsoft R MSDN forum thread recently](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/990bb08c-0d05-4822-88ed-c041c95f563a/exporting-data-from-r-to-sql-server?forum=MicrosoftR) as well.

I ran into this problem and I'm aware of 2 reasonable solutions.

1. Use [sp_execute_external_script](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt604368.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) output data frame option

```SQL
/* Time writing data back to SQL from R */
SET STATISTICS TIME ON

IF object_id('tempdb..#tmp') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #tmp

CREATE TABLE #tmp (a FLOAT NOT NULL, b INT NOT NULL );

DECLARE @numRows INT = 1000000

INSERT INTO #tmp (a, b)
EXECUTE sys.sp_execute_external_script
          @language = N'R'
         ,@script = N'OutputDataSet <- data.frame(a=rnorm(numRows), b=1)'
         ,@input_data_1 = N''
        , @output_data_1_name = N'OutputDataSet'
         ,@params = N' @numRows INT'
         ,@numRows = @numRows
GO
-- ~7-8 seconds for 1 million row insert (2 columns) on my server
-- rxDataStep for 100K rows takes ~45 seconds on my server
```

2. Use SQL Server `bcp.exe` or `BULK INSERT` (only if running on the SQL box itself) after first writing a data frame to a flat file

   I've written some code that does this but it's not very polished and I've had to leave sections with `<<<VARIABLE>>>` that assume connection string information (server, database, schema, login, password).  If you find this useful or any bugs please let me know.  I'd also *love* to see Microsoft incorporate the ability to save data from R back to SQL Server using BCP APIs.  Solution (1) above only works via `sp_execute_external_script`.  Basic testing also leads me to believe that bcp.exe can be roughly twice as fast as option (1) for a million rows.  BCP will result in a minimally-logged SQL operation so I'd expect it to be faster.

```
# Creates a bcp file format function needed to insert data into a table.
# This should be run one-off during code development to generate the format needed for a given task and saved in a the .R file that uses it
createBcpFormatFile <- function(formatFileName, tableName) {
  # Command to generate BCP file format for importing data into SQL Server

  # https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx
  # format creates a format file based on the option specified (-n, -c, -w, or -N) and the table or view delimiters. When bulk copying data, the bcp command can refer to a format file, which saves you from re-entering format information interactively. The format option requires the -f option; creating an XML format file, also requires the -x option. For more information, see Create a Format File (SQL Server). You must specify nul as the value (format nul).
  # -c Performs the operation using a character data type. This option does not prompt for each field; it uses char as the storage type, without prefixes and with \t (tab character) as the field separator and \r\n (newline character) as the row terminator. -c is not compatible with -w.
  # -x Used with the format and -f format_file options, generates an XML-based format file instead of the default non-XML format file. The -x does not work when importing or exporting data. It generates an error if used without both format and -f format_file.
  ## Bob: -x not used because we currently target bcp version 8 (default odbc driver compatibility that is installed everywhere)
  # -f If -f is used with the format option, the specified format_file is created for the specified table or view. To create an XML format file, also specify the -x option. For more information, see Create a Format File (SQL Server).
  # -t field_term Specifies the field terminator. The default is \t (tab character). Use this parameter to override the default field terminator. For more information, see Specify Field and Row Terminators (SQL Server).
  # -S server_name [\instance_name] Specifies the instance of SQL Server to which to connect. If no server is specified, the bcp utility connects to the default instance of SQL Server on the local computer. This option is required when a bcp command is run from a remote computer on the network or a local named instance. To connect to the default instance of SQL Server on a server, specify only server_name. To connect to a named instance of SQL Server, specify server_name\instance_name.
  # -U login_id Specifies the login ID used to connect to SQL Server.
  # -P -P password Specifies the password for the login ID. If this option is not used, the bcp command prompts for a password. If this option is used at the end of the command prompt without a password, bcp uses the default password (NULL).

  bcpPath <- .pathToBcpExe()
  parsedTableName <- parseName(tableName)
  # We can't use the -d option for BCP and instead need to fully qualify a table (database.schema.table)
  # -d database_name Specifies the database to connect to. By default, bcp.exe connects to the user’s default database. If -d database_name and a three part name (database_name.schema.table, passed as the first parameter to bcp.exe) is specified, an error will occur because you cannot specify the database name twice.If database_name begins with a hyphen (-) or a forward slash (/), do not add a space between -d and the database name.
  fullyQualifiedTableName <- paste0(parsedTableName["dbName"], ".", parsedTableName["schemaName"], ".", parsedTableName["tableName"])

  bcpOptions <- paste0("format nul -c -f ", formatFileName, " -t, ", .bcpConnectionOptions())

  commandToRun <- paste0(bcpPath, " ", fullyQualifiedTableName, " ", bcpOptions)
  result <- .bcpRunShellThrowErrors(commandToRun)
}


# Save a data frame (data) using file format (formatFilePath) to a table on the database (tableName)
bcpDataToTable <- function(data, formatFilePath, tableName) {
  numRows <- nrow(data)

  # write file to disk
  ptm <- proc.time()

  tmpFileName <- tempfile("bcp", tmpdir=getwd(), fileext=".csv")
  write.table(data, file=tmpFileName, quote=FALSE, row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE, sep=",")
  # Bob: note that one can make this significantly faster by switching over to use the readr package (readr::write_csv)
  #readr::write_csv(data, tmpFileName, col_names=FALSE)

  # bcp file to server time start
  mid <- proc.time()

  bcpPath <- .pathToBcpExe()
  parsedTableName <- parseName(tableName)
  # We can't use the -d option for BCP and instead need to fully qualify a table (database.schema.table)
  # -d database_name Specifies the database to connect to. By default, bcp.exe connects to the user’s default database. If -d database_name and a three part name (database_name.schema.table, passed as the first parameter to bcp.exe) is specified, an error will occur because you cannot specify the database name twice.If database_name begins with a hyphen (-) or a forward slash (/), do not add a space between -d and the database name.
  fullyQualifiedTableName <- paste0(parsedTableName["dbName"], ".", parsedTableName["schemaName"], ".", parsedTableName["tableName"])
  bcpOptions <- paste0(" in ", tmpFileName, " ", .bcpConnectionOptions(), " -f ", formatFilePath, " -h TABLOCK")

  commandToRun <- paste0(bcpPath, " ", fullyQualifiedTableName, " ", bcpOptions)

  result <- .bcpRunShellThrowErrors(commandToRun)

  cat(paste0("time to save dataset to disk (", numRows, " rows):\n"))
  print(mid - ptm)
  cat(paste0("overall time (", numRows, " rows):\n"))
  proc.time() - ptm

  unlink(tmpFileName)
}

# Examples:
# createBcpFormatFile("test2.fmt", "temp_bob")
# data <- data.frame(x=sample(1:40, 1000, replace=TRUE))
# bcpDataToTable(data, "test2.fmt", "test_bcp_1")

#####################
#                   #
# Private functions #
#                   #
#####################

# Path to bcp.exe. bcp.exe is currently from version 8 (SQL 2000); newer versions depend on newer SQL Server ODBC drivers and are harder to copy/paste distribute
.pathToBcpExe <- function() {
  paste0(<<<bcpFolder>>>, "/bcp.exe")
}

# Function to convert warnings from shell into errors always
.bcpRunShellThrowErrors <- function(commandToRun) {
  tryCatch({
    shell(commandToRun)
  }, warning=function(w) {
    conditionMessageWithoutPassword <- gsub(<<<connectionStringSqlPassword>>>, "*****", conditionMessage(w), fixed=TRUE) # Do not print SQL passwords in errors
    stop("Converted from warning: ", conditionMessageWithoutPassword)
  })
}

# The connection options needed to establish a connection to the client database
.bcpConnectionOptions <- function() {
  if (<<<useTrustedConnection>>>) {
    return(paste0(" -S ", <<<databaseServer>>>, " -T"))
  } else {
    return(paste0(" -S ", <<<databaseServer>>>, " -U ", <<<connectionStringLogin>>>," -P ", <<<connectionStringSqlPassword>>>))
  }
}

###################
# Other functions #
###################

# Mirrors SQL Server parseName function
parseName <- function(databaseObject) {
  splitName <- strsplit(databaseObject, '.', fixed=TRUE)[[1]]
    if (length(splitName)==3){
      dbName <- splitName[1]
      schemaName <- splitName[2]
      tableName <- splitName[3]
    } else if (length(splitName)==2){
      dbName <- <<<databaseServer>>>
      schemaName <- splitName[1]
      tableName <- splitName[2]
    } else if (length(splitName)==1){
      dbName <- <<<databaseName>>>
      schemaName <- ""
      tableName <- splitName[1]
    }

    return(c(tableName=tableName, schemaName=schemaName, dbName=dbName))
}
```

Comment: Bob, thank you, your comment and code snippets you provided were very helpful. I hope MS will do something in the future about this issue, so that there wil no long be a need to use workarounds.

Comment: I had the same problem and ended up writing a bulk insert package for the SQL `bulk insert` command (sorry, no open source due to company policy). Much work, even more problems (like encodings, text column delimiter, UTF-8 not working, setSPN madness...). Is there any way to vote at Microsoft to push a decent solution?